# How to configure riemann with opentsdb

Tags: clojure, opentsdb, riemann

I am a newbie to Riemann and while watching monitoroma videos about riemann, I came to understand that this tool is a wonderful tool for monitoring servers and creating events as well as alerts.

Already I am using opentsdb time series database in my infrastructure and using Hbase to store the metrics. Currently I am interested to integrate the opentsdb
with riemann but really confused with configuration ( riemann.config and opentsdb.clj). I am not sure how to add the opentsdb configuration in riemann.config fileto stream the opentsdb metrics and datapoints.

Please help me how to configure riemann.config file and let me know if you have any sample riemann.config file with opentsdb ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? I would suggest taking a look at [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to post enough details to make sure you get the answer you're searching for.

Comment: Hi PhilDulac, Thanks for your valuable comment. I have added only default config in riemann.config file.  If I am include opentsdb.clj file and service is not starting and suspect that it needs many dependencies to start service.